# Make error in Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I'm trying to install `libgpg-error-1.12` on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. I did all the steps described in the `README` file, but when I run the `make` command I get this output.

```
root@PC-NAME:/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12'
Making all in m4
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/m4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/m4'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/src'
mawk -f ./mkerrnos.awk ./errnos.in >code-to-errno.h
mawk -f ./mkerrcodes1.awk ./errnos.in >_mkerrcodes.h
gcc -E   _mkerrcodes.h | grep GPG_ERR_ | \
               mawk -f ./mkerrcodes.awk >mkerrcodes.h
rm _mkerrcodes.h
gcc -I. -I. -o mkerrcodes ./mkerrcodes.c
./mkerrcodes | mawk -f ./mkerrcodes2.awk >code-from-errno.h
mawk -f ./mkstrtable.awk -v textidx=2 -v nogettext=1 \
        ./err-sources.h.in >err-sources-sym.h
mawk -f ./mkstrtable.awk -v textidx=2 -v nogettext=1 \
        ./err-codes.h.in >err-codes-sym.h
mawk -f ./mkstrtable.awk -v textidx=2 -v nogettext=1 \
        -v prefix=GPG_ERR_ -v namespace=errnos_ \
        ./errnos.in >errnos-sym.h
rm extra-h.in
echo "/* The version string of this header. */" >>extra-h.in
echo "#define GPG_ERROR_VERSION \"1.12\"" >>extra-h.in
echo >>extra-h.in
echo "/* The version number of this header. */" >>extra-h.in
echo "#define GPG_ERROR_VERSION_NUMBER 0x010c00" >>extra-h.in
echo >>extra-h.in
echo EOF >>extra-h.in
mawk -f ./mkheader.awk \
        ./err-sources.h.in \
        ./err-codes.h.in \
        ./errnos.in \
        extra-h.in \
        ./gpg-error.h.in > gpg-error.h
cat ./gpg-error.def.in >_gpg-error.def.h
gcc -E -I. -I..   _gpg-error.def.h | \
      grep -v '^#' >gpg-error.def
rm _gpg-error.def.h
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-init.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-init.lo `test -f 'init.c' || echo './'`init.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-init.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Tpo -c init.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgpg_error_la-init.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-init.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-version.lo `test -f 'version.c' || echo './'`version.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Tpo -c version.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgpg_error_la-version.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-version.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo `test -f 'strsource.c' || echo './'`strsource.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Tpo -c strsource.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgpg_error_la-strsource.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-strsource.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo `test -f 'strerror.c' || echo './'`strerror.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Tpo -c strerror.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgpg_error_la-strerror.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-strerror.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo `test -f 'code-to-errno.c' || echo './'`code-to-errno.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Tpo -c code-to-errno.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Tpo -c -o libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo `test -f 'code-from-errno.c' || echo './'`code-from-errno.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -g -O2 -MT libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Tpo -c code-from-errno.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.o
mv -f .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Tpo .deps/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -version-info 10:0:10    -o libgpg-error.la -rpath /usr/local/lib  libgpg_error_la-init.lo libgpg_error_la-version.lo libgpg_error_la-strsource.lo libgpg_error_la-strerror.lo libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.lo libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.lo   
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libgpg-error.la .libs/libgpg-error.lai .libs/libgpg-error.so .libs/libgpg-error.so.0 .libs/libgpg-error.so.0.10.0
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libgpg_error_la-init.o .libs/libgpg_error_la-version.o .libs/libgpg_error_la-strsource.o .libs/libgpg_error_la-strerror.o .libs/libgpg_error_la-code-to-errno.o .libs/libgpg_error_la-code-from-errno.o    -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgpg-error.so.0 -o .libs/libgpg-error.so.0.10.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgpg-error.so.0" && ln -s "libgpg-error.so.0.10.0" "libgpg-error.so.0")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgpg-error.so" && ln -s "libgpg-error.so.0.10.0" "libgpg-error.so")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgpg-error.la" && ln -s "../libgpg-error.la" "libgpg-error.la" )
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT gpg_error-strsource-sym.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gpg_error-strsource-sym.Tpo -c -o gpg_error-strsource-sym.o `test -f 'strsource-sym.c' || echo './'`strsource-sym.c
mv -f .deps/gpg_error-strsource-sym.Tpo .deps/gpg_error-strsource-sym.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT gpg_error-strerror-sym.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gpg_error-strerror-sym.Tpo -c -o gpg_error-strerror-sym.o `test -f 'strerror-sym.c' || echo './'`strerror-sym.c
mv -f .deps/gpg_error-strerror-sym.Tpo .deps/gpg_error-strerror-sym.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\"    -g -O2 -MT gpg_error-gpg-error.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/gpg_error-gpg-error.Tpo -c -o gpg_error-gpg-error.o `test -f 'gpg-error.c' || echo './'`gpg-error.c
mv -f .deps/gpg_error-gpg-error.Tpo .deps/gpg_error-gpg-error.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o gpg-error gpg_error-strsource-sym.o gpg_error-strerror-sym.o gpg_error-gpg-error.o ./libgpg-error.la  
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/gpg-error gpg_error-strsource-sym.o gpg_error-strerror-sym.o gpg_error-gpg-error.o  ./.libs/libgpg-error.so
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/src'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/tests'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../src     -g -O2 -MT t-version.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/t-version.Tpo -c -o t-version.o t-version.c
mv -f .deps/t-version.Tpo .deps/t-version.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o t-version t-version.o ../src/libgpg-error.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/t-version t-version.o  ../src/.libs/libgpg-error.so
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../src     -g -O2 -MT t-strerror.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/t-strerror.Tpo -c -o t-strerror.o t-strerror.c
mv -f .deps/t-strerror.Tpo .deps/t-strerror.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o t-strerror t-strerror.o ../src/libgpg-error.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/t-strerror t-strerror.o  ../src/.libs/libgpg-error.so
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../src     -g -O2 -MT t-syserror.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/t-syserror.Tpo -c -o t-syserror.o t-syserror.c
mv -f .deps/t-syserror.Tpo .deps/t-syserror.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o t-syserror t-syserror.o ../src/libgpg-error.la 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/t-syserror t-syserror.o  ../src/.libs/libgpg-error.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/tests'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/po'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/po'
Making all in lang
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/lang'
Making all in cl
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/lang/cl'
echo '@errnos@' | cat ../../src/err-codes.h.in - ../../src/errnos.in \
    | mawk -f ./mkerrcodes.awk >gpg-error-codes.lisp
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/lang/cl'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/lang'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/lang'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12/lang'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12'
root@PC-NAME:/home/USERNAME/libgpg-error-1.12#
```

Can you help me please? Thank you

Comment: Looks OK - what's the problem ?

Comment: The errors in the last 9 rows are the problem. If I run 'make install' I get almost the same output and the application doesn't result to be installed.

Comment: I'm with Paul; I don't see any error messages in the last 9 rows, or anywhere else.  This seems to have been a successful build.  Please either quote exactly the error messages you mean, and also describe what you are trying to do and what you expected to happen, and what actually did happen.

Comment: Also make sure when you install you use `sudo make install`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libgpg-error-dev
```